# Class properties in React.js + Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, reactjs

I'm following tutorial on Spring and React integration here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/.
So far everything works great but I wanted to use React Class Properties like

```
static defaultProps = {
...
};
```

but I get an error

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: .../src/main/js/app.js: Unexpected token (23:24)
[INFO] 
[INFO]   21 | 
[INFO]   22 | class MyClass extends Component {
[INFO] > 23 |     static defaultProps = {
[INFO]      |                         ^
```

I tried changing webpack.config.js:

```
query: {
cacheDirectory: true,
presets: ['es2015','es2016','react'],
plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

and adding dependencies in package.json.
I don't get this error anymore but it's still not working and by that I mean - when I open localhost:8080 I can only see blank screen and there is nothing in my MyClass Component beside returning H1 text and with declared class property. Without this class property, it works.
Am I missing something? I am not really sure where to look for errors.

Comment: You can try to do like this instead to solve it at the moment. If your component name is `MyText`, then after your component declaration , write `MyText.defaultProps={...}`.  The above syntax you have written is ES7 `stage-0` syntax which would you can read on yourself how to do it in webpack if you still require that way of writing

Comment: It didn't work with `MyText.defaultProps={...}` unfortunately but I managed to make it work finally so thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work the way I wanted.
First of all, I included `stage-0` and `transform-runtime` in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I added dependencies in package.json:

```
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.5.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0"
```

Then it still wasn't working but I removed **static** keyword in front of `defaultProps` and voilà! It works.